# JQuery Mobile navbar list items not vertically aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery Mobile to mobilize a desktop version of an app. Currently having issues with how the footer displays as shown below:

hmtl:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to "How It Works", about_path,"data-transition"=>"slide", "data-icon" => "info" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Contact",  contact_path,"data-transition"=>"slide", "data-icon" => "mail" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "News",     news_path,"data-transition"=>"slide", "data-icon" => "bars" %></li>
        </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

produces:

[image]

Any thoughts on how I can vertically align all 3 of these links? I've tried the vertical-align css attribute but to no avail.

Comment: Set your list's css to vertical-align: top

Comment: no go with vertical-align: top

Comment: Can you put up a JS fiddle? with some styles of what you have then I can take a better look for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "How It Works", about_path,"data-transition"=>"slide", "data-icon" => "info" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact",  contact_path,"data-transition"=>"slide", "data-icon" => "mail" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "News",     news_path,"data-transition"=>"slide", "data-icon" => "bars" %></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

to this

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="info">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="mail">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="bars">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to use data-role footer.  see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5Lz3zd9y/2/

Alternatively, if you run into this issue anywhere else in jqm with horizontal buttons, here is an easy fix method using the jqm grid. http://jsfiddle.net/Ltx2md34/